# Reassembling an array of words back into a sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok, I'm building a profanity flag for my application. Most of it works like a charm except I can't seem to get an array of words to join together as a sentence again.

```
     $.each(chatHistory, function(key, obj){
        obj.chat_talk = obj.chat_talk.split("+");

            if (flagProfanity(obj.chat_talk) === true){
                //obj.chat_talk = obj.chat_talk.split(",").join(" ");
                $("#chatBody").append(
                "<div class='flag'>"+
                "<div>"+ obj.chat_name +"</div>"+
                "<div>"+"["+ obj.alliance_name +"]:"+"</div>"+
                "<div class='chatMsg'>"+ decodeURIComponent(obj.chat_talk) +"</div>"+
                "<div class='chatTime'>"+ obj.chat_time +"</div>"+
                "</div><br />"
                );
            }else{
                $("#chatBody").append(  
                //obj.chat_talk = obj.chat_talk.split(",").join(" ");               
                "<div class='chatName' onclick='warnee($(this).html)'>"+ obj.chat_name +"</div>"+
                "<div>"+"["+ obj.alliance_name +"]:"+"</div>"+
                "<div class='chatMsg'>"+ decodeURIComponent(obj.chat_talk) +"</div>"+
                "<div class='chatTime'>"+ obj.chat_time +"</div>"+
                "<br />"
                );
            }
    });//End each loop
```

I have tried:

```
obj.chat_talk = obj.chat_talk.split(",").join(" ");
```

and:

```
obj.chat_talk = obj.chat_talk.join(" ");
```

Neither worked. without those lines in the if statement the contents output just fine into the display, just all together with commas between all of em. Put those in and nothing outputs at all.

No errors or warnings on firebug nor any errors from 2 different JS validators.

Content Sample:

```
"chat": [
     {
    "chat_type": 0,
    "chat_id": 445473683,
    "chat_name": "system",
    etc,
    etc,
    "chat_talk": "Chat+messages+here"
    },
    {
    //Another chat message
    }

]
```

This is the contents of obj. obj,chat_thank should contain just the message portion. Then I split the contents at the "+" and run it through the flag function.

EDIT: Profanity flag function code

```
function flagProfanity(object) {
$.each(object, function(key, word){
    if ($.inArray(word, blacklist) != -1){
        return true;
    }
});
return false;   
}//End Profanity flag
```

Comment: What does obj.chat_talk contain? Can you give us an (inoffensive) sample of its contents?

Comment: @ZappTBrannigan shouldn't it be `obj.chat_talk = obj.chat_talk.split("+").join(" ");`?

Comment: So, after the `obj.chat_talk.split("+")` command, `obj.chat_talk` will be an array: `["Chat", "messages", "here"]`. What do you expect to happen when you use `.split()` on an array? What appears in the console looks like a string separated by commas, but it represents an array.

Comment: Well my thought was that it might split it up by the commas but I'm very new to JS. That being said, I did try using just .join() inside the if statement.

Comment: @vihan: The flag function needs it's input to be an array. So I simply split the content into an array so it can be passed into the function. But I'm trying to reassemble it afterwards.

Comment: @ZappTBrannigan I ran your code locally and correctly get "Chat messages here" when using `obj.chat_talk = obj.chat_talk.join(" ");`. Can you post the code for `flagProfanity()`? Maybe it's producing some side-effects.

Comment: As @AlexAlksne points out problem is likely in code that is not show... Side note: consider reading on [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) - not related to your problem, but your sample code looks somewhat vulnerable.

Comment: I will post the filter code in a moment. @Alexei - Security isn't a big issue for this project. The end result will only ever been seen by myself and a few friends.

Answer (score 0):

here's your problem

```
function flagProfanity(object) {
  $.each(object, function(key, word){
    if ($.inArray(word, blacklist) != -1){
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;   
}
```

**return true;**

returns in the context of the anonymous *function(key,word)*

thus it is always false

```
function flagProfanity(words) {
  var found = false;
  $.each(word, function(key, word){
    if ($.inArray(word, blacklist) != -1){
      found = true;
    }
  });
  return found;   
}
```

would work better (Note: i changed the name of the input to make it clear that this is the words list, not an object)

also

```
obj.chat_talk = obj.chat_talk.join(" ");
```

should be what you use to combine the array of strings together

Comment: Looks promising! Thank you! I will plug it in asap and report back. :)